# Can't map network drive hosted on Windows server from Windows client on different network

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, windows-11, mapped-drive

I am trying to connect to a network drive being hosted on a Windows Server 2022 from my Windows clients on different networks. The clients are Windows 10 Home and Windows 11 Home PCs respectively. I enabled port forwarding from my router on port 139.

I connect via the File Explorer by mapping a network drive. For the folder I input `\\<SERVER_IP_HERE>\<DIRECTORY>`, even though I tried it without the  as well.

- I allowed inbound and outbound rules of port 139 on the firewall. I triple checked that my IP and my directory were correct.
- I even disabled Windows Defender temporarily on the clients to see if something were blocking it, but I still could not connect.

Can you help me figure out why it won't connect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure that both TCP ports `139` and `445` are opened on the **Windows Server 2022** machine. Also confirm both those ports are allowed through on your router forwarding and firewall rules where applicable. You might also consider testing and opening UDP port `139` as well.

Check that you can map the drive from the same subnet/network on a different machine to eliminate the Server OS firewall being the issue with it being enabled and disabled. This should help determine if the troubleshooting focus should be on the router port forwarding rule side.

### Supporting Resource

- [SMB: File and printer sharing ports should be open](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/file-server/best-practices-analyzer/smb-open-file-sharing-ports)

  > A File Services Best Practices Analyzer scan reports that firewall
  > ports necessary for file and printer sharing aren't open (ports `445`
  > and `139`).
  >
  > ---
  >
  > To open the firewall ports and enable file and printer sharing,
  > complete the following steps:
  >
  > 1. Open Control Panel, select **System and Security**, and then select **Windows Defender Firewall**.
  > 2. On the left, select **Advanced settings**. The Windows Defender Firewall console opens and shows the advanced settings.
  > 3. In the Windows Defender Firewall console on the left, select **Inbound Rules**.
  > 4. Under **Inbound Rules**, locate the following two rules:
  >
  >    - **File and Printer Sharing (NB-Session-In)**
  >    - **File and Printer Sharing (SMB-In)**
  >
  > For each rule, select and hold (or right-click) the rule, and then
  > select **Enable Rule**.